# Mail being sent with html tags instead of plain text

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, email, sendmail

I am sending a mail by loading the email from a view file.

My email is sent with HTML tags like this:

```
<html><body>Hi mom!</body></html>
```

I want it to be sent without the tags, as plain text:

```
Hi mom!
```

See code below:

```
 public function savepromo(){

        $allemail = $this->AdminModel->getallemail();

        $data['promos'] = $this->AdminModel->getallpromos();

        $totalrows =  $this->AdminModel->countemail(); 
            if ($totalrows > 0) {   
                $limit =  10; 
                $totalbatches = ceil($totalrows/$limit);

                    for ($batch = 0; $batch < $totalbatches; $batch++){

                        $offset = $batch * $limit;

                        $batch_record = array();
                        $destination = "";

                        foreach ($this->AdminModel->fetchrecords($limit,$offset) as $value){
                            array_push($batch_record,$value->email); 
                        }
                            $destination = implode(';', $batch_record);


                            $config = array(

                            'charset' => 'utf-8',
                            'wordwrap' => TRUE,
                            'mailtype'=> 'html'
                            );
                            $this->load->initialize($config);                               

                            $fromemail="mytestingemail@mail.com";
                            $toemail = $destination;
                            $subject = "THIS IS FOR TESTING PURPOSES DONT MIND THIS MESSAGE!";
                            $mesg = $this->load->view('email/promomessage',$data,TRUE);
                            $this->load->library('email');


                            $this->email->from($fromemail, 'MY TESTING EMAIL');
                            $this->email->to($destination);

                            $this->email->subject($subject);
                            $this->email->message($mesg);
                            $this->email->send();
                        }
                    }

        $this->session->set_flashdata('try', '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">SUCCESS!</div>');

        redirect('administrator/createpromo');
    }

}
```

Comment: you mean the recipient sees `<html><body>Hi mom!</body></html>` instead of `Hi mom!`?

Comment: yes is there any wrong in my code?

Comment: you didn't tell CI you're sending an html email, so the html went as plain text, and got rendered as such.

Comment: how can i tell CI that im sending an html email.

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

Comment: is  the config mailtype => 'html' is not telling the CI that im sending a html ? coz i already declared mailtype in my config

Comment: perhaps so. did you do something weird like `htmlspecialchars($html)`, then, and send out `&lt;html&gt;etc...`?

Comment: no all written there is my whole code. actually ive already tried to send an email message before but the whole code is written in $this->email->message(html code) but for me it looks messy that's why i tried it to put in view and i also tried to look for some solutions and still the same output.

Comment: i already figured it out i tried to put $this->email->set_newline("\n"); and
 $this->email->set_mailtype("html"); i my code and it works . but thanks for helping me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell CI the mail type:

```
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");
```

or

```
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
```

Before calling `$this->email->send()`.

Comment: I already solve this problem using $this->email->set_mailtype("html") before you comment. still thanks and i consider your code.